# Can I permanently disallow OS upgrades on an iOS device?

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone, ipad, parental-controls

Is there a way to prevent OS upgrades on an iOS device, such that the user is unable to remove the restriction?

We will be loaning iPhones or iPads to people, and don't want them making ANY changes to the devices.  I see that parental restrictions will let me prevent users from adding or deleting apps, but there isn't an option for OS upgrades.

If I tell iTunes to stop doing updates, and then prevent the user from accessing the iTunes store, will that do it?

Comment: Questions on how to prevent an iOS device from updating isn't on topic here at Superuser

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108314/how-can-i-prevent-ios-7-from-downloading-to-ios-6-devices

Comment: Personal pet peeve: the SuperUser/StackExchange family of sites all have people who gleefully tell you you're in the wrong place, but (1) it's not easy to find the description of which questions are appropriate on which site, and (2) nobody ever says "your question would be appropriate on site X".

Comment: Nobody does it gleefully.  It pains us all deeply, which is why people usually tell you which site is appropriate, if there is one.  Ramhound provided a link to a similar question.  If that doesn't provide an answer, it's a clue as to where this would be on-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Betty: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic -- "Super User...is **not about**:  •electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer"

Comment: @BettyCrokker - I read the help center and thus I know what is and is not on topic here at Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a utility called Apple Configurator, available on the mac app store, that allows you to make a profile for a device and restrict certain features. Preventing updating is on the home screen of the app:
[image]

You can find guides on how to install, and other features on Apple's website: https://www.apple.com/support/business-education/apple-configurator/